# How to fix apple match-o linker id errors in unity project build using xcode 8

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine

I imported a few scenes and assets from one project to this one and now I am getting these errors when I try to build my unity project for iphone in xcode

"_IOSGetAppLink", referenced from:

"_IOSFetchDeferredAppLink", referenced from:

"_IOSFBAppEventsLogPurchase", referenced from:

"_IOSFBAppEventsLogEvent", referenced from:

"_IOSSetShareDialogMode", referenced from:

"_IOSJoinGameGroup", referenced from:

"_IOSFBSdkVersion", referenced from:

"_IOSShareLink", referenced from:

"_IOSFeedShare", referenced from:

"_IOSAppRequest", referenced from:

"_IOSAppInvite", referenced from:

"_IOSCreateGameGroup", referenced from:

"_IOSFBSettingsActivateApp", referenced from:

"_IOSLogOut", referenced from:

"_IOSFBAppEventsSetLimitEventUsage", referenced from:

"_IOSLogInWithPublishPermissions", referenced from:

"_IOSInit", referenced from:

"_IOSLogInWithReadPermissions", referenced from:

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: looks like you forgot to transfer the facebook sdk over too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check FacebookSDK is in on the same project folder or check the path is  correct this error indicates you have missing library or framework.
please this post it will give you better understanding
[Apple linker command fail](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66070)